# what's goes on inside the recursive function

Tags: python, function, recursion

I'm currently learning Python and recursive function. I'm just stuck with it that do not actually know what happened after the recursive step is executed. I have an example such

```
# sum of list
def my_sum(L):
   # this step is just print out current list 
   # at each level
   print(L)
   if not L:
      return 0
   else:
      return L[0] + my_sum(L[1:])
```

and the result for the above function is

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
[2,3,4,5]
[3,4,5]
[4,5]
[5]
[]
15
```

I've read a few articles about recursion and understood a bit. However, in this case, I don't see that size of L is decreased at all, so how can the list is growing smaller like that?

Could someone figure this out for me?

Thank you!

Comment: I understand Python slice notation, and not asking about Python slice notation at all! Thanks.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the question is not about slice, it is about the square bracket notation when calling a recursive function.

Comment: `my_sum[1:]` *is* a slice, there's no special notation with square brackets for recursive function calls. Given that `my_sum` is a function, there'll just be a type error - I think you meant `my_sum(L[1:])`. Note you can [edit] to clarify.

Comment: Yes, that function currently throws: `TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @jonrsharpe yeah, it is a slice I know. But in this case, what I'm trying to figure out is why the list growing smaller like that even the resize of L is not used in the recursive call.

Comment: *"even the resize of L is not used in the recursive call"* - it *is*, the new, shorter sliced list is passed in the recursive call.

Comment: @DavinTryon sorry for the typing error! I've edited the code correctly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe maybe I do not understand well how the slice works in the recursive call. Could you provide me any resources to read about it?

Answer (score 0):

This code: `L[1:]` slices all but the first item from the array.  This is where the array size is decreased.

It is equivalent to `tail`.

So in this example:

`L[0]` is head

`L[1:]` is tail